# Import module into a subfolder

Tags: python

I've looked at a bunch of the other questions on here but none of the solutions worked for me. Here's my directory structure

```
root
  |- __init__.py
  |
  |- app
  |   |- __init__.py
  |   |- main.py
  |
  |- test
      |- __init__.py
      |- unittests.py
```

I want to be able to import a function from `main.py` into unittests.py so I can test it. I have tried the following but kept getting versions of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ___`

```
from root.app.main import function
from app.main import function
from main import function
from ...app.main import function
from ...main import function
from ... import function
import root.app.main as main
import app.main as main
import main
```

Comment: How are you executing this test?

Comment: from the root folder `python3 test/unittests.py`